# ResultSet.isBeforeFirst throws NullPointerException unexpectedly

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
    private ResultSet getResultSet(String id) {
        RDSPooledConnector rdsPooledConnector = connector.getConnector(endpoint, port);
        try (Connection connection = rdsPooledConnector.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
            return preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to retrieve result set {}", id, exception);
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldMove(String id) {
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = getResultSet(id);
            return resultSet != null && resultSet.isBeforeFirst(); // THIS LINE!
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed: {}", id, exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I commented on the line that throws NPE. The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.isBeforeFirst(ResultSetImpl.java:6104)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.isBeforeFirst(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
```

I'm wondering why this could happen, considering that the `ResultSet` is being accessed after the `try` block in `getResultSet` method. So I assume  the connection is closed when it gets to the line where `isBeforeFirst` is called, and even if multiple threads call this method, each will have its own connection.

This is the code for `ResultSetImpl.java`'s `isBeforeFirst`:

```
    public boolean isBeforeFirst() throws SQLException {
        synchronized (checkClosed().getConnectionMutex()) {
            return this.rowData.isBeforeFirst();
        }
    }
```

Apparently `rowData` is null. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Btw you should always close resources like `ResultSet`s.

Comment: @dan1st I see. Do I need to check to see if it is closed or not? `!resultSet.isClosed()`. I'm wondering why it even gets closed in the first place? Even if there are multiple threads, shouldn't each have a different result set?

Comment: I meant that you should close it in any way. Btw, I think it is closed whenever the `PreparedStatement` is closed. Just use one `PreparedStatement` as an attribute

Answer (score 2):

`ResultSet` objects should not really be passed between methods. The comment by @dan1st hit the nail on the head. In method `getResultSet()` you close the `PreparedStatement` and therefore you close the `ResultSet`. If you really want to pass a result set between methods, consider [javax.sql.CachedRowSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply. But how come that it works for 99.99% of the times?

Comment: What you suggest means that it should have never worked.

Comment: @Arian [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can verify your claim.